# Xcode 6.2 - Universal Storyboard Sizing Image Views

Tags: xcode

I am having trouble with creating a universal storyboard for all Apple devices. I am new to AutoLayout and I am wondering how to aspect fit a image so that it will stay in the same position when running different size classes. What constraints would I use? Thank you for taking the time to read this question.

- Also the bottom ImageView is the one needing constraints.

Image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLHsQ.png